single gitlab pages from different jobs
I have 2 gitlab jobs in the same pipeline producing 2 different result ( html reports) that i need to publish to gitlab pages
Job 1 -> creates folder First ( will have html reports)
Run pages to publish which copies folder First under public folder ( public/First)
this works fine
if job 1 is success full run job2
job 2 -> creates folder Second ( will have html reports )
Run page_2 which will copy the Folder Second to ( public/Second)
I saw an example below and tried running the same it does not work for me only the folder which gets publish from Job1 under  public/First works if i point the url to second folder Public/Second it does not work
any help would be appreciated
cache:
  # Required to keep artifacts from old builds, e.g. from master
  paths:
    - public

    pages:  # IMPORTANT! at least one job needs to be named "pages" otherwise the content will not be available
      stage: deploy
      script:
        # copy the pdf file into the public folder
        - mkdir -p public/First
        - cp My_File.pdf public/First
      artifacts:
        paths:
        - public  # instruct GitLab to keep the public folder
    
    
    pages_2:
      stage: deploy
      script:
        # copy the pdf file into the public folder
        - mkdir -p public/Second/
        - cp My_File.pdf public/Second
      artifacts:
        paths: 
          - public  # instruct GitLab to keep the public folder


